# I have set virtual memory at 20GB but the code still could not work due to lack of memory

Tags: c++, memory

Win 7 64bit, 2GB RAM, 20GB virtual memory. Image size: 640 * 480 pixel.

The code mainly do three things:
1) two threads obtain image data from two cameras.
2) two threads push the data into two queues.
3) two threads write the data of queues into two avi files.

In order to make the store process not influences the acquire speed, I split them into different threads. But if I use the same thread acquire image and write image, this problem will not appear because the acquire speed is equal to the write speed.

Using the binary file might help but I am not clear with the reason why virtual memory doesn't work. Any other useful methods? Thank you all a lot.

Comment: Are you actually targeting x64?  If you have only 2GB then your program is liable to die a quick swapping death.  Which exacerbates the firehose problem you have when the camera spits out images faster than you can save them.  The queue just fills up and eventually falls over.  Keeping up with a live camera feed requires a good video codec.

Comment: Yes, you are actually right. No matter how large the virtual memory is, it still needs time to write the data into the disk. The key point is to make the writing speed faster than saving speed. I use the system's codec, which is "x264vfw - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC"

Comment: What do you mean by "code still could not work"? Did you get an error? Did the program behave wrong?

Comment: You are missing the point entirely: If you have 2GB of RAM, increasing the virtual memory will make matters **worse**, not better, because now you are not only streaming data out to the video file, but you are also competing with the memory manager, swapping data out from RAM to your disk drive, and reading it back in.

Comment: Finally I find that the queue can not automatically release the point it stores so that the memory usage increases quickly. I have to delete it manually. `IplImage* temp = frame_queue.front();` `cvWriteFrame(writer, temp);` and `cvReleaseImage(&temp)`. Other statements: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))` and `::SetThreadPriority(write_thread.native_handle(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL)`

Comment: `#include<thread>, <chrono>, <Windows.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but if you are running it as 32-bit app (having 64-bit Win does not make all apps be 64-bit, it will happilly run any 32-bit app) then you cannot use (address) more than 2gb* of memory so adding more does not help. You would need to build and run it as 64-bit app to utilize more than 2gb* of memory by your app.

EDIT: Ok so it seems I was right the first time. :-) 2gb is the limit on Windows (see comments), 4gb is the theoretical maximum that the pointer can address.

Comment: A 32-bit pointer can reference 4GB of memory (address space).

Comment: @IInspectable Right of course. Silly mistake.

Comment: 2GB limit is actually correct (for 32 bit application on windows, unless you set [IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx)), regardless of how much a 4 byte pointer can address.

Comment: I have tried it, but it seems like no matter how large the virtual memory is, it still needs time to write the data into the disk.

Comment: A 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows can access 4GB of memory, if the *large address aware* flag is enabled in the PE header. A 32-bit pointer can **always** address 4GB of memory, even if some of it is not accessible. A 32-bit process on 32-bit Windows can access 3GB of memory, if the *large address aware* flag is set, and the system is booted using the */3GB* switch. Memory is usually not available as a single chunk. Otherwise, a 32-bit process can access 2GB of memory on Windows.